# How to configure multiple firewalls correctly in silex?

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am developing a project where I want to have two login forms one for the administration area of ​​the system and another for access to clients and I have configured the following firewalls

```
'admin'       =>  array(
    'pattern'   =>  '^/.*$',
    'anonymous' =>  true,
    'form'      =>  array(
        'login_path' => '/',
        'check_path' => '/login_check',
        'default_target_path' => '/dashboard',
        'always_use_default_target_path' => true,
        'username_parameter' => 'username',
        'password_parameter' => 'password',
        'csrf_parameter' => 'login_token',
        'failure_path' => '/',
    ),
    'logout'    =>  array(
        'logout_path' => '/logout',
        'target' => '/'
    ),
    'users' => $app->factory(function () use ($app) {
        return new Lib\Provider\UserProvider($app);
    })
),
'clients'      =>  array(
    'pattern'   =>  '^/clients',
    'anonymous' =>  true,
    'form'      =>  array(
        'login_path' => '/clients/login',
        'check_path' => '/clients/login_check',
        'default_target_path' => '/clients/admin',
        'always_use_default_target_path' => true,
        'username_parameter' => 'username',
        'password_parameter' => 'password',
        'csrf_parameter' => 'login_token',
        'failure_path' => '/clients',
    ),
    'logout'    =>  array(
        'logout_path' => '/clients/logout',
        'target' => '/clients/login'
    ),
    'users' => $app->factory(function () use ($app) {
        return new Lib\Provider\ClientProvider($app);
    })
)
```

The 'check_path' => '/login_check' in admin firewall works correctly, But when you want to go to the url generated by the check_path in the clients firewall it marks the following error

```
NotFoundHttpException in HttpKernel.php line 134:    
Unable to find the controller for path "/clients/login_check". The route is wrongly configured.
```

I searched for several hours and I could not correct this error I would appreciate your help in solving it

Thank you

Comment: I wasn't sure from your question, does the `/clients/login_check` path normally work if you just go directly there?

Comment: Hi Mickadoo, I appreciate the attention, when I execute the login form and click to validate credentials it marks the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Your check_path for the "clients" part is not behind the firewall. As the order is significant when defining multiple firewalls (the first matching pattern wins), I'd bet that your "admin" firewall pattern is already catching all URLs, and so the "/clients" URLs are caught by this one instead of the "clients" one.

Maybe try to temporarily rename your admin routes with an "admin" prefix, modify the firewall accordingly (with a pattern catching all "/admin/...") and tell us if it solved your issue, or if the returned error has changed.

**EDIT :**
Or just change the order of your two firewalls, so the clients' one matches routes before the admin's one.

Cheers.

Comment: Wuooooooouuuuu Guigzz very very thank you i change the order and capun my login works.....